# Cannot retrieve existing documents in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I am developing a Java driver the access a `MongoDB` sharded Cluster. When I try to perform the `find()` method on the collection `"test"` of database `"db"`, it returns nothing. However, I have checked through mongo client that there are some documents in that particular collection. Can anyone help? Many thanks.

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /**** Connect to MongoDB ****/
        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress(
            "10.110.198.147", 27017), new ServerAddress("10.110.198.160",
            27017)));
        /**** Get database ****/
        // if database doesn't exists, MongoDB will create it for you
        DB db = mongo.getDB("db");

        /**** Get collection / table from 'testdb' ****/
        // if collection doesn't exists, MongoDB will create it for you
        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("test");

        BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
        document.put("count", "1000");
        coll.insert(document);

        DBCursor cursor = coll.find();

        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So as I understand your code inserts data but doesn't find? Or maybe it doesn't insert it as well? Then maybe you have a mistake in your ip address or port number.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("restaurants").find();

iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
    @Override
    public void apply(final Document document) {
        System.out.println(document);
    }
});
```

Found it on the documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/query/)

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I have tried this but get this compilation error: App.java:40: error: incompatible types
        FindIterable<Document> iterable = coll.find();
                                                   ^
  required: FindIterable<Document>
  found:    DBCursor